# How do I find all vertices in a graph with maximum degree?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given a graph, say

```
g = Graph[{x -> a, y -> c, a -> b,
           b -> c, a -> c, d -> c,
           a -> d, b -> d},
      VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: g]

How do I find all vertices in a graph with the maximum degree i.e. a list of all vertices that has the most number of edges, and highlight them in the graph?

In this case, it would be the vertices `{a,c}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using `DegreeCentrality`:

```
(* In[41]:= *) max = Pick[VertexList[g], DegreeCentrality[g], Max[DegreeCentrality[g]]]

(* Out[41]= *) {a, c}

(* In[42]:= *) HighlightGraph[g, max]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `DegreeCentrality` behaves similar to `VertexDegree` ? +1 for `Pick` that saves few lines and is neater as well [ than my approach]

Answer (score 5):

You can generally highlight vertices by their degree:

```
    HighlightGraph[g, 
 Table[Style[VertexList[g][[i]], 
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
    VertexDegree[g][[i]]/Max[VertexDegree[g]]]], {i, VertexCount[g]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I looked at your blog and vimeo channel, it's very iteresting. :-) A new Mathematica-specific site in the same format as SO will launch in a couple of days.  You can [commit to it here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=23yK9sXkBPQIDM_9uBjtlA2) here to get early access.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have tried

```
HighlightGraph[g, 
 Part[VertexList@g, 
  Flatten@Position[VertexDegree@g, Max[VertexDegree@g]]]]
```

[image: hg]

Same using `Pick`

```
HighlightGraph[g, Pick[VertexList@g, VertexDegree@g, Max[VertexDegree@g]]]
```

Comment: Your solution looks just like what I came up with:`HighlightGraph[g, 
 VertexList[g][[Flatten[Position[vd, Max[vd = VertexDegree[g]]], 1]]]]`  You could highlight the `VertexInDegree` or `VertexOutDegree` by using the respective predicates in place of `VertexDegree`.